# A few Java Generics questions

Tags: java, generics

I'm currently studying Java Generics from a book and there are a few things I don't quite understand.

Suppose I have a parameterized class:

```
class MyClass<T> { 

    T item;

    public T getItem() { return item; }

    // ...
}
```

I understand it is forbidden to create arrays of a parameterized type because of type erasure. Now the book says that I can use casts like so:

```
MyClass<String>[] foo = (MyClass<String>[]) new MyClass<?>[10];
```

but what is the difference to the following statement?

```
MyClass<String>[] foo = new MyClass[10];
```

In both cases at runtime the JVM only knows that `foo` is of the raw type `MyClass[]` right?

Now the book continues to say:

"The result is not safe. If you store a `MyClass<OtherType>` in `foo[0]` and then call a `String`  method on `foo[0].getItem()` you get a `ClassCastException`.
TIP: If you need to collect parameterized type objects, simply use an `ArrayList`: `ArrayList<MyClass<String>>` is safe and effective."

In what way is the usage of `ArrayList` safer in this case? I can produce a `ClassCastException` by storing a `MyClass<OtherType>` in the list just as easily.

**Edit:** I'm not really satisfied with any of the answers. Still the question remains: In what way is the usage of an `ArrayList` safer here? Can anyone give me specific examples that demonstrate that improved safety?

Taking up the following comment to my initial unedited post:

"I think that either the book doesn't explain this well, or you've taken the quote out of context. The problem is when you try to create an array of a generic argument type, e.g. inside MyClass you do `T[] items = (T[]) new Object[10];`"

What's the problem with that?

```
// Please don't comment about any problems related to bounds etc. This class should serve purely 
// for demonstration of the core issue I'm trying to understand
public class MyClass<T> {

    private T[] items = (T[]) new Object[10];

    private int size = 0;

    public void addItem(T item) {
        items[size++] = item;
    }

    public T getItem(int index) {
        return items[index];
    }
}
```

In what way specifically am I losing any type safety that an `ArrayList` can provide?
Please note I'm not trying to make a case for using arrays with parameterized types, I'm sure that Collections in fact do perform better, I'm just trying to understand *why* they do and what problems arise from using arrays.

Comment: No, you can't, at least not without casting it.  The compiler protects you from putting a `MyClass<OtherType>` in an `ArrayList<MyClass<String>>`.  Of course, you can circumvent the compile error by adding casts judiciously, but it would be foolish to do so.

Comment: True, but the same goes for the array?

    `MyClass<String>[] foo = new MyClass[10];
    foo[0] = new MyClass<Integer>(); // Error`

Comment: The compiler won't warn you against storing the wrong thing in the array.  It does try to stop you from storing the wrong thing in the ArrayList.

Comment: That's not true, look at my comment. It doesn't compile.

Comment: Yes, but `MyClass<String>[] foo = new MyClass[10];` _does_ compile but `ArrayList<MyClass<String>> foo = new ArrayList<MyClass>();` doesn't.  So you get the compiler error earlier with the collection.

Comment: Right, but once I have the collection I'm not really better protected than with an array, so it doesn't seem _that_ much safer? After all, storing a `MyClass<OtherType>` in a `MyClass<String>[]` requires pretty much the same amount of work as storing it in an `ArrayList<MyClass<String>>`.

Comment: I think that either the book doesn't explain this well, or you've taken the quote out of context. The problem is when you try to create an array of a generic argument type, e.g. inside MyClass you do `T[] items = (T[]) new Object[10];`.

Comment: Note that arrays and generics really don't play well together. Store things in an `ArrayList<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why is "safer" to use generic Collections vs naked arrays is because the compiler adds extra reassurance that your code will do what is intended as it is less likely that you will mix references to objects created with different type-arguments due to a coding error from your part.

For example it is totally legal to add a mixture of `MyClasses` into a `MyClass` array:

```
MyClass<Integer> mcInt = new MyClass<Integer>();
MyClass<String> mcString = new MyClass<String>();
MyClass[] array = new MyClass[] { mcInt , mcString }; 
...
MyClass<String>[] typedArray = (MyClass<String>[]) array;
```

The above may compile ok (depending as to how you handle unsafe warnings), however, `typedArray` will contain an invalid reference to a `MyClass<Integer>` typed element.

With generic collections the equivalent code won't ever compile because the compiler, thanks to the added type safety provided by using generics, realizes that you are adding that invalid reference.

```
MyClass<Integer> mcInt = new MyClass<Integer>();
MyClass<String> mcString = new MyClass<String>();
List<MyClass<String>> list = new ArrayList<MyClass<String>>(); 
list.add(mcString); // is ok.
list.add(mcInt); // won't compile.
```

You are welcome to use naked array but by doing that you are losing additional checks done by the compiler. In practice is is ok to use the unsafe arrays if these are private fields or local variables, you are extra careful and silence warnings using @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") when you are sure that your code is actually safe as far as the compiler would assured it to be if you were to use generics.

In my experience, most of the time is best just to use generic collections whenever you can but sometimes you may get in situations in where the unsafe alternative is far more convenient due to performance or just because the safe alternative results in more cumbersome code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still I don't really see any additional type safety.
Your `list` is of type `List<MyClass<String>>` so yeah, the compiler realizes an error when you try to add an object of type `MyClass<Integer>`.
But the same happens when you use an array:
`MyClass<String>[] arr = new MyClass[10];
arr[0] = new MyClass<Integer>(); // Error!`

Comment: @yakmiras The problem is that array may already contain a MyClass<Integer> instance as I shown in the code example... the **damage is already done**. Further access thru the strongly typed reference won't cause any additional damage.

Comment: @yakmiras  Another scenario is that some other component has gain access to that same array using a variable or field with a different generic type-parameter and in that case you could be adding a mix of elements to the same array. Once you are ok with a un unsafe cast then why not two or four.

Comment: @yakmiras, the bottom line is that as long as you take care of business either solution would be equally safe in practice... however since coding is not perfect and there is always bugs hiding around, chances are that over-time (lines of code) if you keep using unsafe casts when you have the option not to you are going to have in average an additional bug due to that...

Comment: Right, so I guess the difference is that you can't do the following:
`List<MyClass> foo = new ArrayList<MyClass>(); /* Add instances of MyClass<Whatever> */ List<MyClass<String>> bar = foo; // Error!`

Comment: @yakmiras you can, if you use an additional cast to a raw type for example.